# Update all the fields of a table in Web SQL HTML5

Tags: html, web-sql

In a general Update sql statement we need to map each of the fiields to their new values using `column1=value1` and .....(so on so forth).

I need to update `all the columns of a row (8 columns are present)` and thus this mapping is very tedious to do.

As i searched, i got an answer of SO stating `(column1,column2 .....) = (value1,value2...)` works for SQL. However i need to run this query for WEB SQL (HTML5) and this form does not seem to work.

Can any one please confirm the same and suggest any short form of performing an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Even if it worked, `(column1,column2 .....) = (value1,value2...)` doesn't save you that much, you still have to write all the columns and values. Just use the `column1=value1, column2=value2` approach (and use bind variables for the values).

Comment: Yeah I guess i would have to , its Just that it save me the mess

Answer (score 1):

Well it is possible to minimise the mess via the use of arrays to hold the values in the executeSQl statement.

Troubled souls may visit [here](http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/) to check on the INSERT and UPDATE query sections.